# What graphics engine is used in Photoshop

Tags: graphics

I am wondering what is the default graphics engine used in Photoshop?
It's great tool. And I don't know how they make it?

I mean, if I want to create a simple tool like it, I will use MFC/GDI+.
So, what is core to make Photoshop being great tools?

Comment: remember that Photoshop is _way_ older than any of these.  Heck, it's older than any desktop OS in use!

Comment: @Walter: 10x, I'm a vietnamese. I'm not pretty good in English. And your comment about **"Photoshop is way oder"**... is lighting me.

Answer (score 14):

They have a custom graphics engine written directly against the APIs of the OS's they code for. That's one of the things that sets them apart from the rest of the graphics tools out there is that they aren't just using the stock junk that comes built into the APIs.

As for the core -- it's people. Brilliant, hard-working, well-paid people.

Comment: I like to think at least *some* of the code is still [Thomas Knoll's original](http://photoshopnews.com/feature-stories/photoshop-profile-thomas-john-knoll-10/) from "Display" written on his Mac Plus! He was still the lead developer on the Photoshop team up until version CS4.

Comment: What? Graphics engines are software? Written by people! But surely programmers are just people who glue together existing APIs, and the APIs are these magical gifts from the gods!

Comment: @Steve314: I'm part of the propaganda machine. I put forth nonsensical information to give mortals the hope of being able to mingle with the gods. The gods don't get paychecks, they feed off the souls of the unworthy.